# Background Container Div Hyperlinked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `Bootstrap V3.0.1` website and I need to make the container div hyperlinked. The HTML layout is similar to the following:

```
<div class="g-content-wrapper">
    <div class="Sidebar1">Text And Links here</div>
    <div class="Main-Content">Text And Links here</div>
    <div class="Sidebar2">Text And Links here</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.g-content-wrapper {
    background: #828282 url(../img/Black-Background-Fabric-Wallpaper.jpg) fixed center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add a link around it?  Although if you have links in the other sections, then why would you need an overall link and how would you expect that to work as you can't have nested links

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to achieve. This is a typical XY problem and solutions for it will not be accurate without sufficient details.

Comment: Or maybe you would like the div to act like a link, but only if you do not click a link inside? Because that can be done with some javascript or jQuery

Comment: I'm trying to link a background image on my website to a page within my website. My website for better reference: https://www.gbets.co.za/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either instead of `div` use `anchor` tag, or just surround your div with `anchor` tag.

**Solution 1**

```
<a class="g-content-wrapper" href="your_page.com">
    <div class="Sidebar1">Text And Links here</div>
    <div class="Main-Content">Text And Links here</div>
    <div class="Sidebar2">Text And Links here</div>
</a>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<a href="your_page.com">
    <div class="g-content-wrapper">
        <div class="Sidebar1">Text And Links here</div>
        <div class="Main-Content">Text And Links here</div>
        <div class="Sidebar2">Text And Links here</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Though it is better to use `anchor` tag rather than surrouding a div with it.

If you want just the inside divs to be a link you can apply the same but inside this div.

**Example**

```
<div class="g-content-wrapper">
    <a class="Sidebar1" href="your_page1.com">Text And Links here</a>
    <a class="Main-Content" href="yor_page2.com">Text And Links here</a>
    <a class="Sidebar2" href="your_page3.com">Text And Links here</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

**Assumption**

If you would like the div to behave as link but not when clicked on link inside you can do it like this:

```js
$(".g-content-wrapper").on('click', function() {
  location.href = 'your_page.com';
});

$(".g-content-wrapper a[href]").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.g-content-wrapper {
    background: #828282 url(../img/Black-Background-Fabric-Wallpaper.jpg) fixed center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="g-content-wrapper">
  <div class="Sidebar1">
    <a href="test.com">Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Main-Content">Text And Links here</div>
  <div class="Sidebar2">Text And Links here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete There are no links inside.

Comment: Test and links here x 3!

Comment: Exactly "Text And Links here" is a string. Not a link.

Comment: Err that is OP being lazy and showing you the content of those divs will be text and links rather than actually showing the html of the content